# RTMP request parameters for stream settings

Tags: nginx, rtmp

I'm using nginx-rtmp module for streaming ip-camera, it works fine untill camera address is hardcoded. But when i trying to send address in RTMP PLAY request things goes messy.
Example of request:

```
213.160.158.86 [07/Aug/2015:09:58:29 -0400] PLAY "myapp" "test" "addr=rtsp://admin:pass@123.123.123.123:554/h264/ch1/sub/av_stream" - 799 1571372 "http://www.hdwplayer.com/rtmp-player-wowza-streaming-online/" "WIN 18,0,0,209" (5m 18s)
```

Here is my conf:

```
rtmp {
server {
    listen 1935;
    ping 30s;
    notify_method get;

    application myapp {
        live on;
        exec_options on;

        exec_pull ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i $arg_addr -vcodec copy -an -f flv "rtmp://localhost:1935/myapp/test";


}
}
```

As you can see $arg_addr not works, and stream not starts.